# Why won't it print out 0? Beginner query

Tags: printing, integer, zero, out

This is a program that prints out all the even numbers between any given integer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question1
{
    private int i;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give me a number!");
        int i = scanner.nextInt();

        if ((i % 2) != 0)
        {
            i = i - 1;

            do
            {
               System.out.println(i);
               i = i - 2;
            } while (i != -2);
        }
    }
}
```

So, if I give the number 11, it will print out 10, 8, 6, 4, 2. Why won't it print 0 as well, since my while statement contains i!= -2 and 0 counts as an even number?

Answer (score 0):

Because after `scanner.nextInt();` you must put `scanner.nextLine();` else, the last element the scanner gets from `nextInt();` will be ignored.

Even so, your algorithm is extremely dizzy. why not try:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
int number = in.nextInt(); in.nextLine();
for( int i = 0; i <= number; i += 2 ) {
    System.out.println( i );
}
```

?